# eager loading "with" statement is not returning corresponding relationship data on selecting specific columns

Tags: laravel

**Firstly, I try this:**

```
Route::get('/admins', function () {
    
 return Admin::with('roles')->get();  
});
```

It returns all admins along its corresponding roles **BUT** when i try to select columns:

```
Route::get('/admins', function () {
    
 return Admin::select(['username', 'email'])->with('roles')->get();  
});
```

It select and returns all admins but with `[]` roles..
**What is the issue here ?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the columns that take part in completing the relationship.

In your case, it's `id` that is **missing**.

```php
Route::get('/admins', function () {
    
 return Admin::select(['id', 'username', 'email'])->with('roles')->get();  
});
```

Comment: oh!! Got it, Thank you @steven

Comment: @GunarajKhatri , you're welcome.